How can I inspect the error returned by UDPConn.Read?
Our system occasionally sees this error returned by *net.UDPConn.Read(byte[]):

read udp [::]:7089: wsarecv: A message sent on a datagram socket was
larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit,
or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the
datagram itself.

(The read buffer is bigger than the MTU)
As this is probably a data error rather than a network error, I would like to test for this error so that I handle it appropriately.
What value can I give to errors.Is to identify these errors?
*update - running on Windows, this appears to correspond to winsock WSAEMSGSIZE message, how do I code that into Go?

Before digging down and trying to match a very specific system error, first ask yourself what you intend to do with it. You can’t control for this error on your side, and in almost all cases you will handle non-temporary network errors the same.

True "never test for an error that you don't know how to handle".  I am currently testing for a timeout, but otherwise default action for a UDP receive error is to close and reopen the socket, however these particular errors come in bursts for a few minutes at a time and I think I can probably just ignore them, at  least I would like to test that theory.  ie I think this is a temporary error.

Try dumping the error (with tools like spew or utter) to see if identifiable types or values occur.

In addition to what @Volker said, you could start with a simple fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err).

Thanks.  I'll have to google spew & utter...
The message I quoted came from fmt.Printf("%v", err), I'll see if "%#v" gives me more.

I've added log.Printf("%#v\n", err), so now we've been running a day or so without seeing any errors.  I'll report back when I find something.

%#v gives me:
&net.OpError{Op:"read", Net:"udp", Source:(*net.UDPAddr)(0xc0005cc330), Addr:net.Addr(nil), Err:(*os.SyscallError)(0xc000094080)}
which is still pretty cryptic.  I'll either leave it alone and close & re-open the socket or I will have to use @eik's suggestion and import x/sys/windows.

You can import golang.org/x/sys/windows and then do:
import (
    "errors"
    "net"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func ...(conn net.Conn) {
    // ...
    _, err := conn.Read(...)

    if errors.Is(err, windows.WSAEMSGSIZE) {
        // ...
    }
}


I have been using the windows.WSAEMSGSIZE call and checking the size of large packets.  So far I have set the buffer size to 2304 (which I think is max packet size on wifi) and I am still receiving packets larger than this, so I will continue to expand the buffer until the errors go away!  Thanks.
